# Using dynamic css class loading in sveltekit

Tags: sveltekit

I have an app where I want the user to be able to override the default design of his page.

I'd like to have a template with default styles, then have the user override what he wants.

Here's a example of code: The wanted feature is the last line in `<style>` dynamically inserting `{styles}`

```html
<script>
    const styles = {
        right: {
            "background-color": "#ff0000",
            "color": "#00ffff",
        }
    }
    
</script>
    
<div class='profile-page'>
    <div class='left'>
        <!--some stuff-->
    </div>
    <div class='right'>
        <!--other stuff-->
    </div>
</div>
    
<style>
    .profile-page {
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .left {
        flex: 1;
        background-color: #26878b;
    }

    .right {
        flex: 2;
    }

    {styles}
</style>
```

The **{styles}** is not accepted here, is there a syntax to insert its content?

Answer (score 1):

That is not supported/intended. The preferred way of customizing styles is via custom properties.

E.g.

```css
.left {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: var(--background-color, #26878b);
}
```

```html
<div class='left'
     style:--background-color={styles.left.background}>
    <!--some stuff-->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, this is already very interesting. I just have to check if I can turn fill class attribute through a special property (a Lit.dev custom element property) as described in this article: https://css-tricks.com/using-custom-elements-in-svelte/
This would make the class attribute completely editable. And make the solution transparent (using regular <style> content, but being able to append things to it)